# how do we restrict an update to be performed by an trigger only

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

i have requirement in which opportunities of a particular record type can only updated by an trigger. In other words, updates should not happen from ui or data loader.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. The brute force way would be to restrict the application account's permissions to perform INSERTs/UPDATEs on the table.

Comment: As Brad says, lock down security so that it can't be updated by various profiles (probably apart from admin). Triggers will still be able to update records without issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following code to a "before update" trigger, and roll back whatever changes people make to a record before it's commited to the database.  In the same trigger you could put whatever other changes you want it to make.

something like

```
for(Account a : Trigger.new){
    if(a.recordtypeId != 'recordTypeToExclude') continue;
    a = Trigger.oldMap.get(a.id);        
}
```